# iOS ARView.hitTest limited to a max of 100 meters

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, hittest, realitykit

I found that `ARView.hitTest` is limited to 100 meters distance.
All objects located further than 100m, regardless of size, are not recognized.

Is there any way to unblock this?

```
let hitTest = arView.hitTest(point, query: .any, mask: .all)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, a distance limitation of `hitTest(_:query:mask:)` instance method is 100 meters at the moment. But you can implement method `raycast(from:to:)` allowing you to shoot a ray from any scene point to any direction, even if a distance is 1000 meters.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let cameraPosition = arView.cameraTransform.translation
    
    let castHits = arView.scene.raycast(from: cameraPosition, to: [0, 0,-1000])
    
    guard let hitTest: CollisionCastHit = castHits.first else { return }
    
    print(hitTest.distance)
}
```

Update:

Additionally, as @Sacha suggested, we can use instance method [ray(through:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/3243245-ray) that determines the position and direction of a ray through the given point in the 2D space of the view. It returns optional tuple `(origin: SIMD3<Float>, direction: SIMD3<Float>)?` that suits for arguments of `raycast(from:to:)` method.

Comment: thanks @Andy, will the vector [0, 0,-10000] be orthogonal to the screen in this case? Actually what I'm trying to do is to implement the ability to touch the object without distance restrictions

Comment: Found the way to do it using: let ray = arView.ray(through: tapPoint), let results = arView.scene.raycast(origin: ray.origin, direction: ray.direction, length: 1000, query: .nearest)